# Why there is an Error while checking error on SEO checkup sites

Tags: error-handling

At the time of checking errors regarding my [home loans](https://www.hdfc.com/home-loans-salaried) website with SEO Check up tools, there is an error message which comes every time (that message contains your site is not live). but actual my site is already live in google index, what is the reason for this error message.